# Temporary change letter with another lookalike [Linux Mint]

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Recently, I was [succesfully](http://pastebin.com/PqEAcYu3) changed letter *o* with some looklike letter.
Now I wanna also change my letters *a* and *e* with this one **ᶏ** & **ҽ**, using `xmodmap`. (than I will create script to enable/ disable this when I need it). This morning I tried and tried to find a way but nothing; I was hope [this](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap) will help me but no, think I don´t understand this (yet). Thanks.

PS: Sorry if this question is not on the right place, I´m newbie.

Comment: What exactly did you try that didn't work? We are not a script writing service, you need to be more specific about what is your issue. From the question link it seems like you got an answer (in comment) *how* to do it. It'd be helpful if you post your code, what you expect it to do and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Although I understand what you are doing, I don't get the point... can't you just use a COMPOSE key, the character map, or a swap keyboards to the appropriate language? Mint, like most distros, has tools built in to do this.

Comment: @ Adalee I´m not posted this to expect working scripts.
True, I´ve got answer, it works but with _o_ letter. I trying to replace just another 2 letters but without success (cause it is Greek_SIGMA).


@acejavelin  I don´t want to replace all letters on keyboard, that´s why I´m not change it to the appropriate language. Can you be more specific with COMPOSE? Thanks.

Comment: @se0D2 You can use the Linux Compose function... In keyboard layout, options, assign a location to Compose key (Right-ALT or Scroll Lock are common) and press and hold the Compose key then enter a combination from /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose. For example, COMPOSE+oc is ©

Comment: As I am understand, you think on this - create keyboard shortcut (Alt+o etc)? That´s not the point; maybe my english is not too good to understand - when I pressed letter _a_ I want to see ᶏ. :) That´s it. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @se0D2 I guess it depends how much you use it, to use compose for this you would hit Compose+a, (a then comma) like so ą